# How to carousel in loop?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to loop carousels with class "active" first item

here is my code

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="top-top">
        <h4>some heading</h4>
        <iframe class="testimonial" width="100%" height="auto"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ynK2WIRg?rel=0" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>

@foreach($test as $tes)
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="top-top">
        <h4>{{ $tes->name }}</h4>
        <iframe class="testimonial" width="100%" height="auto"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $tes->file_name }}?rel=0" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

I trying to put active item in the loop too.

Comment: How do you choose the active element?

Comment: right now i am choose active element from outside the loop but I wanted to put this in loop too

Comment: I can see that. I wanted to ask on what criteria do you choose which element will be the active one. Some variable value? Or simply the first element?

Comment: simple! first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$loop->iteration==1` as said in [laravel blade doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) inside the foreach:

```
@foreach($test as $tes)
    <div class="carousel-item @if($loop->iteration==1) active @endif">
        <div class="top-top">
        <h4>{{ $tes->name }}</h4>
        <iframe class="testimonial" width="100%" height="auto"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $tes->file_name }}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) inside a loop:

```
@foreach($test as $tes)
<div class="carousel-item@if($loop->first) active@endif">
    <div class="top-top">
        <h4>{{ $tes->name }}</h4>
        <iframe class="testimonial" width="100%" height="auto"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $tes->file_name }}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **loop variable**

Inside your loop you can access to many useful information, like if it's the first or last loop, the current loop count, if even or odd... Here you can find all the info in official doc

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
@foreach($test as $tes)
    @if ($loop->first)
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="top-top">
            <h4>{{ $tes->name }}</h4>
            <iframe class="testimonial" width="100%" height="auto"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $tes->file_name }}?rel=0" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    @else
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="top-top">
            <h4>{{ $tes->name }}</h4>
            <iframe class="testimonial" width="100%" height="auto"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $tes->file_name }}?rel=0" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```